# Regex to allow insensitive alphabets, numbers and special chars like comma, dot, hash and hypen

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation

I tried the regex `^[a-zA-Z0-9,#-.\s]*$` to allow insensitive alphabets, numbers and special chars like comma, dot, hash and hypen and spaces to sanity check for US addresses like "928 Mill Samy Dr, Apt #23AB-23" or "P.O Box #2323" in a html input field using javascript. But this regex also takes other special chars than i specified in the regex like ()&* etc...

Comment: What didn't work? Explain the problem!

Comment: The regex shown seems to pass the example addresses that you mention and reject other characters like `&`. Please [edit] your question to show the actual JS code you used, then show the incorrect output for those sample inputs. (Also, you don't mean "alphabets", you mean "letters", or perhaps "alphabetic characters".)

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to edit your question to provide the solution. If you want to share what worked, do so by writing an answer in the space below provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details about how it works

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following regex works for US addresses like "928 Mill Samy Dr, Apt #23AB-23" or "P.O Box #2323" `/^[a-zA-Z0-9,#\-.\s]*$/i`

Answer (score 2):

`-` in your regex means "to", `#-.` means characters `from # to .`, i.e. `#$%&'()*+,-.`

To filter out `-`, you should use `\-`

This site is good for testing regex:
https://regex101.com/